# ROS with MATLAB on 2 computers on protocol

Tags: matlab, websocket, udp, ros

I would like to know if it is possible to connect **ROS** and **Matlab** together without using the toolbox from Matlab.

I'm using **Matlab 2014b** and the toolbox is not supported for this version of Matlab.

Also, I need to use this version of Matlab because the "**Quanser board**" I will be using is only compatible with the 2014b version of Matlab.

So, I was thinking of maybe using **UDP** to send packets from Ros to Matlab and vice versa.
I will be using **2 different computers** for the task.

I'm a beginner in ROS and Matlab in general.
I hope you guys can guide me in the right direction!

Comment: Can you use https://www.mathworks.com/help/ros/ref/node.html

Comment: @GPrathap that method requires me to have the ROS Toolbox from Matlab which I'm not able to use.